# Pass a parent datetime parameter to a drillthrough report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a main report and a drillthrough(child) reports. Both work very well. But there is an issue with passing parameters.

prodID and @Date. On the main report you would click on the prodID to provide the prodID for the child and that is good. Now, the issue is passing the second parameter(@Date) to filter the result set returned but it happened that there is no matching column to match the @Date parameter to when setting up the Action dialog box because there's no such a column as a datetime data type in the child report except in the where clause. Before now we would have to supply the @Date value manually. How do I modify my query or work around this so the @Date parameter is passed on to the child report as well at run time?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the action dialog box, instead of selecting from the drop down insert the following 
`=Parameters!Date.Value`

you could also press the fx button and the browse to your parameter